# A good iPhone app for it when standing in the dock

Tags: iphone, applications

I have an Apple dock for my iPhone 4 and find it beautiful so I like to have it in my desktop or my bed table while charging. The thing is I'd like to have a simple app that shows me the time, weather, maybe a small brief of my social network accounts, dunno just useful info so the phone isn't just standing there with the screen off.

I find difficult to find something like this with a decent graphics quality in the iTunes Store. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [Alarm Clock](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/alarm-clock-pro/id335678373?mt=8) (there's a free version, but with an ad on the bottom, so not very "beautiful").

[image: alarm clock pro]

It shows the time of the day (obviously) and can also show the date, and the weather/temperature.
Nice touch: sliding your finger increase/decrease brightness.

(But no social network)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this and get exactly the look you want is to create (or find) a web site that displays that.  Go to it on Safari, and make a web clipping out of it.